# Why can't I use STILT as verb in this sense?

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives

I had hitherto assumed that one could easily switch from an *adjective* to a *verb* and vice-versa, considering many adjectives (*participle adjectives*) are formed from verbs. But it seems that there is no such freedom to be always enjoyed.

**For example, while it is fine to write either**

> This task is really tiring.

Or

> This task really tires you.

**It isn't correct to write**

> Strict adherence to the rules of grammar sometimes **stilts** your prose.

I have to recast the sentence instead as

> Strict adherence to the rules of grammar sometimes **makes your prose stilted.**

Why is this the case and is there a way to know where such *switching between verb and adjective forms* isn't allowed, without having to check the dictionary?

Comment: Whoever told you  *Strict adherence to the rules of grammar sometimes **stilts your prose*** is somehow "incorrect" is mistaken. It's perfectly valid (albeit not particularly common), as is reference to [***stilting the discourse***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stilting+the+discourse%22) (metaphorically, artificially and unjustifiably "elevating" one's words/register in an attempt to sound sophisticated, but actually coming across as ***affectedly pompous***).

Comment: ...it's just a straightforward metaphorical allusion to the literal state of *being raised up on stilts* - also popularised in the everyday expression [***nonsense on stilts***.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nonsense+on+stilts%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk01ZaxYJydrV3mNAv-V5w9npRirKvA:1610369077433&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB78Sm9JPuAhVC1hoKHW7LDqIQpwUIJg&biw=1339&bih=711&dpr=1.25)

Comment: @FumbleFingers— That's how I'd also thought it to work, but none of the recognized dictionaries lists this use of *stilt*. And hence the question. But thanks for providing references. Makes it easy to have uniformity in such patterns.

Comment: 'Stilt' as a verb in the metaphorical sense is apparently so uncommon (I didn't realise this) that even [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stilt#Verb) doesn't list it. I remember examples very similar to this one: 'As previously noted, injuries have somewhat stilted his progress' (From the Google search for "stilted his progress"; Jack Wilshere mentioned in some capacity).

Comment: You can verbify just about any noun and nounify just about any verb in English. I imagine that ***stilt*** was probably a noun before it became a verb in "architectural" contexts (propping up arches, or whatever). But I just went to [a typical online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stilt) (Merriam-Webster), and they list the ***literal*** definition of the verb as well as the noun. They don't actually define the "adjectival past participle" metaphorical usage either, so it's obviously not that important from their perspective.

Comment: @FF Pun noted. Groan registered.

Comment: You question is itself ungrammatical. You cannot say what you said. It must be either "Why can't I use...?" or "Why can I not use...?".

Comment: @tchrist Possibly 'unacceptable on non-idiomatic grounds'. FF has explored usage at [Is it incorrect to say 'Why cannot ...'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50251/is-it-incorrect-to-say-why-cannot).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, you can -- as the commenters have pointed out -- but it's not common usage and you will get various complaints and/or weird looks.

To answer your second question, there is no way to know in advance. You have to check the dictionary. I don't have any sources for this because it's a fundamental feature or bug of the English language -- it's not uniformly governed by rules, but rather rules that work some or most of the time and a sea of particulars that you just learn over time.

Comment: Yes, why can't English be more well-behaved!